# Google Analytics Traffic Source issue

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I'm having an issue with Traffic sources. Sometimes when i'm receiving traffic it doesn't identify the sources and when i click on it displays false data. It could last for an hour and then it does fix itself.Here are the samples:

1. It shows "?????" on the Traffic source

[image]

2. When i click on it i see false numbers which are 100% incorrect

[image]

3. Here's how it should be on a regular day

[image]

Can anyone please advise what is wrong? How do i fix it?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related but related to the Google Analytics web application may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

There is no a real solution however it is a false problem.

It's probably a real-time bug, here you can find here other users who have had the same problem:

- https://support.google.com/analytics/thread/14249554?hl=en
- https://support.google.com/analytics/thread/14009798?hl=en

The support does not seem to say anything about it, however it will resolve itself and does not compromise the data actually acquired.